# How to obtain reference data in a microservices architecture?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, microservices, aws-serverless

We are migrating a monolithic application to a microservice architecture and are aiming to go on a serverless path. We have developed independent services on AWS lambda and the UI is written with Angular.

There is some reference data (from an external source), and we need suggestions on the best path to follow for fetching this data.

For example: we have to display Employee details and we get employee IDs from a service. To display the employee names based on IDs, we have to make a call to the external source. Similarly for Company names, etc.

So far we have two approaches. What are the pros and cons? Is there another approach that we should consider?

---

Approach 1: We do this service(our microservice) to service(external source) call at service layer (AWS lambda) and return the complete desirable result to UI for display.

Approach 2: We return employee ids to UI and Angular UI makes a call to the external source to display data in the desired format (display names and company descriptions).

Comment: Since you are already using AWS, you _could_ consider AWS AppSync which uses GraphQL - doing this means that you would be able to consolidate AWS resources in a single request from the client.

Answer (score 0):

From a microservices best practices standpoint, the first approach is better. You will have a service with the purpose to work all the data you need to be sent to the client. It may be fetching the data from outside or from other services, but you want data work to be centralized, avoiding the client to depend on different services.